# How to extract and stitch together a multipart tar arcvhive without the initial file

Tags: tar, data-recovery, dd, compression

I have a large folder with multi part tar files each 2gb in size, file.partaa through  file.partgy, however I am missing the initial tar file. Is there any way that I can extract each part individually and then stitch them together?

I realize that this will break whatever file is first, however I can sacrifice that file if all of the other parts can be stitched back together.

Note: these files are not compressed, just plain old tar.